# How to set window level in Swift

Tags: swift

I am having trouble with the window level constants such as `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel`. Swift complains about unresolved identifier. I couldn't find an enum equivalent of these levels either ? Is this possible currently ?

I'm trying to use:

```
window.level = NSScreenSaverWindowLevel // unresolved identifier
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following through the chain of defines:

```
#define NSScreenSaverWindowLevel     kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel
```

and...

```
#define kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel     CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey)   /* 1000 */
```

I think the corrected answer is:

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey)))
```

much casting because of discrepancies in enum types

Comment: I think this definitely answers the question. One might add that  `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` was an alias for `kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey`, though.

Comment: The solution by @david works but is definitely very ugly. Something Apple must fix in the next drop

Comment: `window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.CursorWindowLevelKey))` now works